# Import error in Truffle Pet Shop tutorial

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm executing an example in the Truffle [Pet Shop tutorial](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop).

While testing with file `TestAdoption.sol`, I have encountered the following error:

```
Source truffle / Assert.sol not found
```

The source code causing the error is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol"; // error source truffle / Assert.sol not found"
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";// error source truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol not found"
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

}
```

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Typically your files will all lie in the `contracts/` directory within the truffle project root folder.

If the other contracts are in the same folder as this you need to change your import statements - `./` represents the current folder

```
import "./Assert.sol";
```

Comment: Sorry for not checking it out. Although the code line error, the compile still works well. It took me a long time to fix it. I hope the software development team will fix this error.